# QueryException\nException Description: Missing descriptor for [interface javax.persistence.Tuple].\nQuery: ReadAllQuery

Tags: java, spring-boot, jpa, spring-data-jpa, openjpa

While using projection in JPA, i recieve above mentioned exception.

```
@Query(value = "SELECT c.name, c.DateTime, SUM(c.items)" + " FROM tableas AS c WHERE c.DateTime <=?1 GROUP BY c.name",  nativeQuery = true) 
    List<ProjectionParamas> getItemssByName(Date dateTime);
```

Do you have any idea ?

Regards,
Stephan

Comment: Sorry , query is:                                                                                                   
 @Query(value = "SELECT c.name, c.DateTime, SUM(c.items)" + " FROM tableas AS c WHERE c.DateTime <=?1 GROUP BY c.name",  nativeQuery = true)                                                  List<ProjectionParamas> getItemssByName(Date dateTime);

Comment: Have you tried with `SELECT * FROM tableas`?? Whether it's working fine??

Comment: What is `ProjectionParamas` show details?

Comment: Exception arises only if i use projection. In case of List<Object[]> it works .ProjectionParams is a projection:                                                                              
  public interface ProjectionParams {
        
        String getName();
        
        Date getDateTime();
        
        int getItems;
        
    }